# Access a web application with a port number iis

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET` application that I'm trying to upload to a server. the server is `Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard` with `IIS 7.5`.
 The server IP address is like so: 212.199.xxx.yyy:zzz and is accessible using `RDP`.
I placed the application files in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite` and added it to `IIS` by right clicking the `Default Web Site` and selecting `Add Application`.
when I browse to the site like so `http://localhost/MySite` is works but if I try to access it from another computer like this `http://212.199.xxx.yyy:zzz/MySite` I get a `This page can’t be displayed` message.
I also added an `Everyone` permission to the application files. could it be because of the port? what else can I do to make it work?

Comment: If `http://localhost/MySite` works then it is clearly running in port 80. When you say you tried `http://212.199.xxx.yyy**:zzz**/MySite`, I am understanding you are trying a different port. Is the `Default Web Site` bound to that port? If so, is it bound to any IP or only a specific one?

Comment: Another point to note. Does `http://localhost/MySite` works when you use a browser other than Internet Explorer? Because IE will use Windows Authentication with `localhost` and access the page logged in as Administrator. This can be deceiving when debugging the problem.

Comment: how can check if the default web site is bound to a port? the site is accessible using localhost and chrome too.

Comment: Right click it and choose `Edit Bindings...`

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is told IIS that your Default Web Site is an application in itself.  If you want MySite to be the application, you'd need to right-click that folder in IIS and select "Add Application".  After that, you'd access the new application using something like `http://212.199.xxx.yyy:zzz/MySite` (assuming that `http://localhost` gives the same page as `http://212.199.xxx.yyy:zzz`; typically you access a site with just `http://212.199.xxx.yyy`).

And as you're accessing the folder rather than the start page directly, you'll need to make sure that the page you want it to display as the default is listed in the "default documents" for that folder/application.